# Count data in a Structural Equation Model

Tags: poisson-distribution, structural-equation-modeling, negative-binomial-distribution, count-data, lavaan

I want to fit a structural equation model (SEM) on using the `lavaan` package in `R`.

Some of the most important variables in my model are count data, e.g. abundance of different species, and thus do not follow a normal distribution.

I tried to transform some of my variables to obtain normal distributed data but this results in an output that is uninterpretable: positive relationships become negative, effect sizes are meaning less.

I have added a figure which basically displays my problem: all the species variables are the count data and these species affect the other species through predation. `habitat` and `climate` are my latent variables. I am not really interested in these latent variables, so a solution without these would also be a solution.

[image]

## Question(s):

*Is there a way to model this network assuming a negative binomial or Poisson distribution for my species variables?*

`Stata` has something called Generalized SEM, but this does not return standardized estimates and it doesn't return any measure to validate the model.
I really need standardized estimates, because I am most interested in the indirect effect of `Species C` on `Species A` via `Species B`.

*Are there other techniques to model these kind of networks?*

Comment: Mplus allows count variables (including Poisson, zero-inflated Poisson and negative binomial) to be modeled.

Comment: @Maxim.K Thanks for the suggestion. Do you know if Mplus gives standardized estimates when using these alternative distributions?

Comment: I can't imagine why not.

Comment: @Maxim.K I had a look at Mplus. It seems that it is not possible to get standardized estimates (st.est.) when having count variables that also function as independent variables. I am able to get st.est. when I only treat species A as count data but not if I do this for any of the other species. I guess it has to do with the fact that standardizing data to a mean of 0 and st.dev of 1 makes no sense when variables are not following a more or less Gaussian distribution.